# Popup maker plugin causes issue with multiple popups on a single page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, popup, megamenu, divi

I am using the Popup Maker plugin with Divi Page Builder. I need to call more than 5 popups on a single page. When I tried to set up 2 popups on the mega menu I got a conflict with page design & popup design.

I have referred to articles https://docs.wppopupmaker.com/article/196-display-multiple-popups-at-the-same-time & https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-popups-problem/ but still facing issues with the same.

I want to display a popup for highlighted menu items and other links from pages. Please refer below image:

[image]

Please find original design in below image:

[image]

After conflict design is as below image:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an Answer from Popup Maker plugin support.

There was a conflict between Divi Builder & Popup Maker plugin CSS. When I tried using custom html it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Might be there some CSS conflict between divi theme and popup builder, try with your owl style

Answer (score -2):

Set the position of those popups to absolute, it should fix the problem, if not, feel free to send me a message.

Comment: not working when position absolute or fixed

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WQpQRhLZkPgC-RX_rTg1GH705EwIVXWE/view?usp=drive_link

Please find screen recording of my issue.